# 403 - forbidden when commiting code (tortoiseSVN)

Tags: svn

the SVN client successfully determines that only one file changed. When I try to commit:

```
POST of '/p/s****/code-0/!svn/me': 403 Forbidden
```

is made. I tried to delete and check out the whole project - the same. It doesnt do the same on the other projects, and all projects goes to one "SourceForge" registrating.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Subversion stores auth-data for each **repository** separately (even if they share some part of URL)
2. If you have write (commit) permissions on this project (check it on project admin-page), you may have anonymous checkout enabled - and in this case checkout doesn't add and store authentication data
3. You can try to commit

   - From command-line and in case of error show **full output** of command
   - add `--username USER` and `--password PASS` to the commit command options /for one, successful commit, only/

Comment: finally its OK.... I had to use the "https" method, so username+password was asked